# A more transparent highlighting with Defer and evaluate-in-place?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, formatting

I’m using Highlighted[Defer[…]] on expressions and evaluate-in-place to highlight parts of queries for a book project.

Works well usually, but I notice it leaves out the quotations, see image - those should be strings. Strings should also be gray.

Is there an option to Highlight while leaving the other natural input form highlighting as-is?

[image]

Toy example. Use shift-command-return (OSX) on `Highlighted[Defer["a"]]` to highlight

```
<| "a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> // Query[Highlighted[Defer["a"]]]
```

Comment: Seems not related to `Defer` so much as the fact that `Highlighted` formats like output rather than input, even if it is in an input cell.  The quotes are gone because quotes don't show up in output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Highlighted` takes the nigh-ubiquitous [`BaseStyle` option](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle.html), allowing you to set [`ShowStringCharacters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowStringCharacters.html) to `True`. If you want the highlighting to "hug" the content closely, you can use the [`ContentPaddinng`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContentPadding.html) and [`FrameMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameMargins.html) options:

```
Highlighted[
 Defer[Query[{"Gaze/patient", "Physical exam"} /* Apply[Join]]],
 BaseStyle -> {ShowStringCharacters -> True},
 ContentPadding -> False, FrameMargins -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Pillsy, very nice. What about color? Strings in gray.

Comment: Nevermind, colors render fine on Mathematica, so in your example the black strings be due to SE highlighting.

Comment: Any way to make the vertical aspect of the panel small enough so that it doesn't affect line spacing?